# getting response data on logger interceptor

Tags: typescript, logging, nestjs, interceptor

I am trying to log the response data by using logger interceptor, but when I send a new request I get output

```
before
undefined
after
```

instead of what i expect to get

```
before
<response data>
after
```

this is my log interceptor

```
export interface Response<T> {
    data: T;
}

@injectable({scope: Scope.REQUEST})
export class TransformInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T,Response<T>>{
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>>{
        console.log('before')
    return next.handle().pipe(tap((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        console.log('after');
        return data;
    }));
    }
}
```

and this is the appModule

```
@Module({
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [ ControlLogger, AppService, {provide: APPINTERCEPTOR, scope: Scope.REQUEST, useClass: TransformInterceptor}]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

and i am not sure this is relevent but this is my app controller

```
@Get('isActive')
requestfunc(@Req() req: Request, @Res res: Response){
res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send('Active')
}
```

(i have also tried switching the tap to async map)

hope you can help me to log the response data

Comment: I believe this is expected as you choose to use the [library-specific mode](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object). Instead of `.send('Active')`, do `return "Active"` and add the option `{ passthrough: true }` to your `@Res()` decorator

Comment: thank you so much that solved the problem.